# cmake --build ignores MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2015

I'm using windows 10, cmake 3.17 and Visual Studio 2015 and I'm trying to include a vcxproj into my CMake project. My CMake has two config `Debug` and `RelWithDebInfo`. My vcxproj in the other hand has `Debug` and `Release`. With the help of the `MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_RELWITHDEBINFO` properties, I managed to map `RelWithDebInfo` with `Release` and it works perfectly when I'm using visual studio on the generated Solution. But the issue comes when I'm using `cmake --build` command. When I do that, I've got the following error  `error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio 2010 (Platform Toolset = 'v100')` because the build try to build my vcxproj with `RelWithDebInfo` config which do not exist.
The following code is what I use

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(add_vcxproj)
include_external_msproject(project1
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Project1/Project1/Project1.vcxproj
)
set_target_properties(project1 PROPERTIES
      MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_RELWITHDEBINFO Release
      )
```

I do not understand why my project try to use `RelWithDebInfo` instead of `Release`.
Do you guys have an idea on how to force `Release` for `Project1` with `cmake --build` command?
Thanks :)

Comment: Having you looked at this link? https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/18026 It seems no solution is planned though for the ticket is two years old.

Comment: Thanks. This two issues are not the same but seem related... :(